# How to add multiple modules with support design support libraries

Tags: android, android-design-library

I am working on one old project it uses two modules and adds them in root project, one of the module has this setting in build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')
}
```

whereas the app project has this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22'
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 13
        targetSdkVersion 22
        applicationId 'xxxxxx'
        versionCode xxx
        versionName 'xxx'
        multiDexEnabled false
    }
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("xxxx")
            storePassword "xxx"
            keyAlias "xxx"
            keyPassword "xxxx"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            ext.enableCrashlytics = true
        }

    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':androidsupportv7appcompat')
    compile(project(":xxxlibraryForActionBar")) {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile files('libs/commons-io-1.3.2.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

and my root project has

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {

        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

When I change (in app build.gradle) compile sdk to 23 and build tools to 23.0.1 and add 
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0', it gives me error that there are some attributes that have already been defined, I know that it is conflicting with one of the added libraries that is both are declaring same fields but how to resolve that.

```
Error:(268) Attribute "windowActionBar" has already been defined
Error:(268) Attribute "windowActionBarOverlay" has already been defined
Error:(268) Attribute "windowFixedWidthMajor" has already been defined
Error:(268) Attribute "windowFixedWidthMinor" has already been defined
Error:(268) Attribute "windowFixedHeightMinor" has already been defined
Error:(268) Attribute "actionBarTabStyle" has already been defined
Error:(268) Attribute "windowFixedHeightMajor" has already been defined
```

Although after udating everything to newer version now i am getting

Attribute showDivider already exists, I found out that as android merges all values files at that time it is conflicting but can't find any solution, I have tried to go in appcompactv7 values folder and change name of showdivider but that creates other problems.

Comment: The later `build.gradle` file that you mentioned is at `root` project level or `app` module level? I think it is at `app` module level.

Comment: you are right it is at app module level, i have 3 of them, i will be updating it with my root build.gradle in a second.

Comment: I have edited the question, with further details, do you have any idea how can i resolve that conflict?

Comment: I write my answer below. We should not use any support library .jar files which usually cause conflicts. Add library dependencies instead.

Comment: I am giving it a shot, i had suspected that but as i am no expert needed guide and expert opinion will let you know about how did it go. thanks

Comment: Hope you get rid of this. Maintaining an old project is painful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, remove these dependencies in both `build.gradle` files. They are added in Eclipse's style and cause conflicts.

```
compile files('libs/android-support-v7-appcompat.jar')

compile project(':androidsupportv7appcompat')
```

Replace them by using `support-v7` library only by adding this line under `dependencies` in both `build.gradle` files.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v7:21.0.0'
```

Also, you should consider to replace this because I think it is deprecated.

```
compile(project(":xxxlibraryForActionBar")) {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

Finally, you set minSdk is 7, so you even do not need this dependency. So, you can remove it.

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, you were right, once i did this just had to change action bar as that was old and it was crashing, it worked though.